# What is the name of this equation and what do the variables mean?

Tags: derivation-of-formulae

[click here to view equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atl9Q.png)

I came across this (Friedmann) equation here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-calculate-age-of-universe-with-a-certain-redshift.69285/

I want to use it but am not sure what it means. Could somebody provide the name and/or what the variables stand for?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't this be a better fit for https://physics.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: $t$ is [cosmic time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_time); $a(t)$ is the [cosmic scale factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_factor_(cosmology)); $H_0$ is the [Hubble constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law).

Comment: The $\Omega$ are [density parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model) for matter ($m$) and dark energy ($\Lambda$). The “,0” subscript means “at the present time”.

Comment: *I want to use it but am not sure what it means.* If you don’t know what the equation means, why do you want to use it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Ghoster's comments said it all.